# Can pytest xdist tests log to the same configuration?

Tags: python, logging, pytest, xdist, pytest-xdist

I'm using pytest with the xdist plugin to run a large suite of tests. These tests can take a few hours to run, so I'd like to see certain information while they are running. The items I'd like to see are the errors when tests fail, how many tests are still left, and more. To do this, I'd like to have a setup where detailed errors go to one file while basic info like how many tests are left will go to another file. Is there a pytest plugin that would allow this or a way to hook up the internal pytest logger to do this?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find something I could really use for this so I wrote my own plugin for pytest and xdist. Here it is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-single-file-logging
Not sure I like the name though.

Answer (score 0):

pytest-sugar does it for example
at the sprint in june we hope to enhance the api further